# How can I look up the used JDK in a Homebrew Formula?

Tags: java, macos, homebrew, artifactory

I am writing a new Homebrew Formula, which provides [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/), a Java based program.

I want to adjust memory settings, if it is run on a special Java version. How can i programmatically check, which Java version is provided by OS X?

Currently, I use this approach, where the user has to define an option:

```
option "with-java8", "Adjust memory settings for Java 8"
# Remove obsolete parameters for Java 8
inreplace "bin/artifactory.default",
    '-server -Xms512m -Xmx2g -Xss256k -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+UseG1GC',
    '-server -Xms512m -Xmx2g -Xss256k -XX:+UseG1GC' if build.with? "java8"
```

It would be nice to make the option obsolete.

I found the following dependency in other Formulas:

```
depends_on :java => "1.7"
```

but couldn't find a documentation for this feature. Is there a resource available what tools homebrew provide to work with Java formulas?

Comment: I have no clue in writing formulas, but cheapo for writing one for Artifactory! We'll love to mention it in the user guide.

Comment: @JBaruch Nice to hear it is in JFrog's interest as well. I will send you a message after the formula will have been merged into Homebrew. Meanwhile you can give it a try here: https://github.com/timomeinen/homebrew/tree/artifactory